# Session variables set but don't carry over

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm trying to create a login system, as part of that i would like to use sessions to create an array called 'user' which contains the current logged in user's details - the information comes from a mySQL server if user login successfully

Note: i made sure to start all files with:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

The problem is that every time i use

```
$_SESSION['user']['name'] = $row["user_name"];
```

(value can be anything even fixed)

If i redirect, reload or simply manually change to another page where i have something like

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "<p>Welcome user ".$_SESSION['user']['name']."</p>";
?>
```

It will simply print
Array ()
Welcome user

I have tested to see if the session variables are set by putting code or trigger after

```
$_SESSION['user']['name'] = $row["user_name"];
```

which works fine, i can run if statements based on them and print them fine which would suggest the variables are set correctly

Specific details:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4Ywn.png)

PHP: 7.4.10

login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'connection.php';

if(isset($_REQUEST['loginButton']) ){
    $userEmail = filter_var(strtolower($_REQUEST['userEmail']),FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $userPassword = strip_tags($_REQUEST['userPassword']);

    if(empty($userEmail)) {

        $errorMsg[] = 'Email Required';

    }else if(empty($userPassword)) {

        $errorMsg[] = 'Password Required';
    }
    else{
        $select_stmp = $db->prepare("SELECT * from user_l WHERE user_email = :email LIMIT 1");
        $select_stmp->execute([':email' => $userEmail]);
        
        $row = $select_stmp->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($select_stmp->rowCount() > 0){
            if(password_verify($userPassword,$row["user_password"]) ){

                $_SESSION['user']['name'] = $row["user_name"];
                $_SESSION['user']['email'] = $row["user_email"];
                $_SESSION['user']['prem'] = $row["user_prem"];
                $_SESSION['user']['job'] = $row["user_job"];

                header("location: index");

            }
            else{
                $errorMsg[] = 'Email or password incorrect';
            }
        }
        else{
            $errorMsg[] = 'Email or password incorrect';
        }

    }


}

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'connection.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) ){
    header("location: login");
}
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "<p>Welcome user ".$_SESSION['user']['name']."</p>";
?>
```

connection.php

```
<?php

include '/********/cred_cr.php';

$db_host = $servername;
$db_user = $userT;
$db_password = $accounts_register_detailsDB;
$db_name = "********";

try{
        $dsn = "mysql:dbname={$db_name};host={$db_host}";
        $db = new PDO($dsn,$db_user,$db_password);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

Summary, variables are set as i can run code like printing or echo in file login.php after they are set. which would also suggest the database connection is working and the PDO part is fine but I'm not sure anymore, please help if you got any ideas what I'm missing or doing wrong with setting the variables somehow to local?
Apologies if there are similar posts but i could not find anything that would help resolve my case.

Thank you

Comment: double check the session driver and other settings in php.ini and try to skip the "verify password" step (or make absolutely sure that you got it right). It's been a while since I played with sessions, but I don't see anything obviously wrong in your code.

Comment: Did you check the error logs for any clues? Maybe a `Headers already sent` error

Comment: Are cookies set? Have you tried using "regular" `.php` files (without Rewrite)?

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions and hits that helped me so much to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

The hint and suggestions in the comments, that i should be looking at my settings and my error logs let me to discover i was getting error "file or directory not found" on line 2 (both at session start and session read)
Then i simply wrote a "session_save_path" just above "session_start();" and now everything works great!
For some reason my default session path has issues so i simply created a new path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).